# Help installing LG ultra-wide screen (29UM58) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lg

I can't get my LG ultra-wide screen to work on my ubuntu laptop. Here are my specs:

- LG Model: 29UM58 plus Startech USB 3 to HDMI adaptor
- Laptop: ThinkPad T430
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (4.8.0-040800-generic)
- Graphics Card's...

...description:

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:27 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

From the advise I got [here](http://www.gadgetoid.com/2011/12/31/usb-to-hdmi-and-dvi-adaptors-reviewed/), I also tried installing the DisplayLink drivers from [here](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads). Nothing worked.

Comment: After connecting the screen to your laptop, can you run this command:
`xrandr --listmonitors`
(If xrandr is not available, please install it)

Comment: @PyGeek03 Thank you for the reply. I got:  

` Monitors: 1`  
 `0: +*LVDS1 1600/309x900/174+0+0  LVDS1`

Comment: OK so only the screen that comes with your laptop is detected... I guess this is really a driver problem. Have you tried rebooting your laptop after installing that driver?

Comment: @PyGeek03  I tried. I'm starting to suspect that I'm installing the wrong driver.

Comment: Maybe you should download the driver from here: https://www.startech.com/Downloads

Comment: I couldn't find a solution, but using the minDP to HDMI adapter  found through the link below was the best solution for me. It worked automatically

StarTech.com MDP2HDMI Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Video Adapter Converter: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-MDP2HDMI-DisplayPort-Adapter-Converter/dp/B00310EEO4/